# What event occurs immediately after a control is displayed for the first time?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, user-controls

I know there is `UserControl.Load`, which occurs before the control becomes visible for the first time. And I know there is `UserControl.HandleCreated`, which occurs when a handle is created for the control.

But I'm looking for what event occurs when the control is actually shown for the first time.

**Reason:**

I am dealing with a `DataGridView` which has a bunch of data put into it before the control is shown. I can't color the rows (`BackColor`) without the control being painted (the commands simply don't work). The commands to color rows only works once the control has been painted for the first time. So I need to capture that event and colorize the rows at that point.

```
dataGridView1.Rows[index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

The above line works when the control is shown but does not work with the control is not shown.

Comment: Have you tried the `RowPrePaint` or `RowPostPaint` event?

Comment: not quite sure, but I would like to recommend http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete.aspx the DataBindingComplete event. As it also handles the resize events depending on contents, this should ( imho ) work vor your painting aswell

Comment: Why can't you override `OnPaint`?

Comment: The event after the control is loaded, and before it is rendered is called [OnPreRender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.web.ui.control.onprerender%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault see the tag, this is winforms

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`VisibleChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visiblechanged.aspx) event.

```
private void UserControl_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Visible) { ... }
    else { ... }
}
```

Comment: ClientSize can have zero values here. Even if Visible is true.